# How do I invoke a command in a Tcl thread asynchronously from a non-tcl thread?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, tcl

I'm doing some work in a C thread (I'm using pthreads) that is not associated with an Tcl interpreter. It possesses pointers to the ThreadId and TclInterp of an existing Tcl thread, and would like to send a script to this Tcl thread to be evaluated asynchronously.

I can do it with [XThreadUtil](http://wiki.tcl.tk/15342) synchronously and only if I block the Tcl thread until the C thread finishes execution. I really need the asynchronous behaviour. That is, the desired sequence of events is:

1. tcl thread invokes command that spawns C thread and returns immediately;
2. event loop of tcl thread resumes, C thread concurrently does its work;
3. when C thread finishes work, it posts an event to the tcl thread's event queue and exits;
4. tcl thread processes event when ready.

I've tried using the Tcl thread notification API (Tcl_ThreadQueueEvent/Tcl_ThreadAlert), and the async API (Tcl_AsnycCreate/Tcl_AsyncMark) with not much luck. I haven't been able to find much in the way of examples. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Tcl_ThreadQueueEvent](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/Notifier.htm) and Tcl_ThreadAlert is what I've used in the past. You need to remember the thread id of the Tcl main thread for the alert call using Tcl_GetCurrentThread.

There is an example in [tmsWinMailslot](http://git.patthoyts.tk/?p=tms;a=blob;f=win/tmsWinMailslot.c;hb=HEAD) if you look at the MailslotSignalledProc which raises Tcl events from a worker thread that is monitoring the Windows mailslot in this code. Its using Windows overlapped I/O so once some data becomes available on the blocked worker this function reads and posts it to Tcl as an event then starts reading again to wait for some more data.